# Calculate Expectancy of Poisson distribution with Poisson parameter

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The problem:

> Let X have the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, where $\lambda >0$.
>
> Calculate E[X!] for every possible value of  $\lambda$,

So what I got so far:

$$E[X!] = \sum_0^\infty\frac{i!\cdot e^{-\lambda}\cdot\lambda^i}{i!} = e^{-\lambda} \sum_0^\infty\lambda^i=\frac{1}{e^\lambda\cdot(1-\lambda)}$$

Is this correct?

Help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Well it holds for $\lambda < 1$ I believe...

Comment: yes that's correct